# Erroneous output from parse_address using EXTENSION address_standardizer

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to clean and parse addresses and am not getting the parsing results between two queries using the same extension "address_standardizer".  In my main query, only certain cities were parsed.  State and zip are fine.  However in testing to see why it is missing most cities, I see the cities in a test query.

I am using the same base query [here](https://postgis.net/docs/parse_address.html) modified as:

```
SELECT city, (a).num, (a).street, (a).city, (a).state, (a).zip, (a).zipplus
FROM (SELECT city, parse_address(city) As a
 from add_data
where city ~ ', *\D\D \d{5}$') AS p;
```

This results in:

```
city                    |num|street |city|state |zip  |zipplus
HONOLULU, HI 96819      |   |       |    |HI    |96819|
NEW YORK, NY 10018      |   |       |    |NY    |10018|
NEWHALL, CA 91321       |   |       |    |CA    |91321|
LONG BEACH, CA 90815    |   |       |    |CA    |90815|
LYNNFIELD, MA 01940     |   |       |    |MA    |01940|
CHATTANOOGA, TN 37407   |   |       |    |TN    |37407|
```

So I tested with:

```
select city, parse_address(city) as cty
from add_data
where city ~ ', *\D\D \d{5}$';
```

Which gives me the expected parsing of city, state and zip:

```
city                        |cty
BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213     |(,,,"BEVERLY HILLS",,CA,90213,""US)
OXNARD, CA 93031            |(,,,"OXNARD",,CA|93031,""US)
STREETSBOSO, OH 44241       |(,,,"STREETSBOSO",,OH,44241,""US)
OMAHA, NE 68114             |(,,,"OMAHA",,NE,68114,""US)
CHATTANOOGA, TN 37401       |(,,,"CHATTANOOGA",,TN,37401,""US)
CUYAHOCA HEIGHTS, OH 44125  |(,,,"CUYAHOCA HEIGHTS",,OH,44125,""US)
```

I'm not sure where I'm off on my query to lose the city being parsed, while it still handles the state and zips. How would I rewrite the query to get the proper parsed results?

Comment: It would be worth including all of the fields in the output record to see if there's a mismatch.  Looking at the second output, and counting commas, it looks like 'OXNARD' might be being put in the address1 field.

Comment: No - the output of each query is exactly as you see it.  The only field used from my data in the table is 'city'.

Comment: I think I see where you are heading with that - if I back up from the state, then comma, it appears as if the city is being shoved in a street address slot due to the comma in the data. But no, as shown in the first output, the street and city (and num) columns are all null.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_address` expects a complete input, or some indications that parts of the address is missing.

First, it helps to show the output column names: We see that the city is not parsed, as it is in the `address1` column, which is an aggregation of the street information.

```
select (parse_address('BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213')).*;
 num | street | street2 |   address1    | city | state |  zip  | zipplus | country
-----+--------+---------+---------------+------+-------+-------+---------+---------
     |        |         | BEVERLY HILLS |      | CA    | 90213 |         | US
(1 row)
```

If we add a street info, then the city is properly identified.

```
select (parse_address('123 ab street BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213')).*;
 num |  street   | street2 |   address1    |     city      | state |  zip  | zipplus | country
-----+-----------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+---------
 123 | ab street |         | 123 ab street | BEVERLY HILLS | CA    | 90213 |         | US
(1 row)
```

To properly parse the city name of an address that does not contain a street, you would need to explicitly tell that there is no street info by adding a leading comma.

```
select (parse_address(',BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213')).*;
 num | street | street2 | address1 |     city      | state |  zip  | zipplus | country
-----+--------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+---------
     |        |         |          | BEVERLY HILLS | CA    | 90213 |         | US
(1 row)
```

Note that adding a comma between the street and city is also required with not standard street type or complex cases:

```
select (parse_address('123 ab MystreetType BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213')).*;
 num |         street          | street2 |          address1           | city  | state |  zip  | zipplus | country
-----+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------
 123 | ab MystreetType BEVERLY |         | 123 ab MystreetType BEVERLY | HILLS | CA    | 90213 |         | US
(1 row)


select (parse_address('123 ab MystreetType, BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90213')).*;
 num |     street      | street2 |      address1       |     city      | state |  zip  | zipplus | country
-----+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+---------
 123 | ab MystreetType |         | 123 ab MystreetType | BEVERLY HILLS | CA    | 90213 |         | US
```

Comment: No - if I concat in the street address with or without the added comma as in your example, all it does is push the street address to the city field on output.  This is from messy data, where on many rows, the city, state ZIP are all in the "CITY" field in the table. If I use a nice full string as in your example it works fine, but not to clean messy data it seems.